# PEP8 warning when accessing protected member from classmethod

Tags: python-3.x, class, class-method

This one has me scratching my head. I fixed it but I still would like to know why this warns me of this problem.

I have a protected class method `_parse_string` and I want to implement logging for it. The reason is that I want debug information available should something go awry and the user wants to know what they passed to the method. I set up a protected member in the class to reference the logger (because I don't want users of my library touching the logger object - only my class should do that.

```
class myClass:
    myClass._logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    @classmethod
    def _parse_string(cls, raw_string: str) -> str
        cls._logger.info('Call to _parse_string method.')
        cls._logger.debug('_parse_string input: {0}'.format(raw_string))
        return raw_string.rstrip()
```

On the 5th and 6th lines of code that read `cls._logger.info('Call to _parse_string method.')
cls._logger.debug('_parse_string input: {0}'.format(raw_string))` it gives me an warning that I am accessing a protected member.

But I'm accessing said 'protected' member from a `@classmethod` inside the myClass class, so why the warning?

I found the solution was to do:

```
class myClass:
    myClass._logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    def _parse_string(self, raw_string: str) -> str
        self._logger.info('Call to _parse_string method.')
        self._logger.debug('_parse_string input: {0}'.format(raw_string))
        return raw_string.rstrip()
```

Just removing the `@classmethod` decorator and changing the cls references to self.